# SQL query to sum the hours worked by employees per week

Tags: mysql, sql, sum

I am trying to get a sql query that will allow me to sum the amount of hours a person has completed in a week , below is my sql query i have at the moment

```
SELECT 
Name, 
DATE_format(Start,'%u') AS Week, TIMEDIFF(`End`,`Start`) as Hours_Worked, sum(TIMEDIFF(`End`,`Start`)) as Weekly_hours_per_employees 
FROM roster 
group by Name
```

this is my table that i have

below is the output i am getting for the sql query

any help would be much appreciated , thanks!

Comment: Please stop adding screenshots. See: [Why should I provide an MCVE for what seems to me to be a very simple SQL query?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-an-mcve-for-what-seems-to-me-to-be-a-very-simple-sql-query)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use week also in group by

```
SELECT 
Name, 
DATE_format(Start,'%u') AS Week, sum(TIMEDIFF(`End`,`Start`)) as Weekly_hours_per_employees 
FROM roster 
group by Name,Week
```

Comment: do you have advise on how i can convert the Weekly_hours_per_employees  to hours and minutes

Comment: @KatieODonovan use TIME_TO_SEC(TIMEDIFF(`End`,`Start`)) and then your hour will be trnaser into sec then you can convert as your wish

Comment: i have added a new screenshot of the code i have updated however the format is not correct when added two shifts in the same week together